# Google Map in Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am using Google Map in my app. The map is fine on the device, but in BlueStack App Player, the text is unreadable as shown in [the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex0VM.png).

Code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
  android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just a scaling discrepancy between bluestacks and your actual resolution. Nothing to worry about, and also nothing to do with the bit of XML you posted.

Comment: You can modify bluestacks internal resolution: http://itekblog.com/change-bluestacks-app-player-resolution/

Comment: But I assume you're using bluestacks because you WANT it to emulate a higher screen resolution, in which case you should probably leave it as is. It'll look fine on an actual tablet.